# Flutter : operable program or batch file. Error: Could not find or load

Tags: android, flutter, dart, gradle

Every time I want to create new project and run it this error is shown

> 'apps\tic\android' is not recognized as an internal or external
> command, operable program or batch file. Error: Could not find or load
> main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain Exception: Gradle task
> assembleDebug failed with exit code 1 Exited (sigterm)

& can't accept android licenses

> flutter doctor --android-licenses Error: Could not find or load main
> class we

and I can't fix them by anyway